# Diseñar matriz en report viewer visual studio c#

Tags: c#

Hola estoy creando un reporte en c# con la herramienta report viewer.

Tengo un dataset de una consulta de dos tablas unidas por el inner join. Y el resultado es el siguiente:

ID_EMP         | NOMBRE            | FECHA_ASISTENCIA               | TIEMPO |

0001                    Juan            17/05/2019               8.6

0001                  Juan            18/05/2019               8.6

0001        Juan            19/05/2019               8.6

0002        Carlos          18/05/2019               8.6

0002       Carlos           19/05/2019               8.6

---

El campo ID_EMP y NOMBRE son de la tabla empleados

Y los campos Fecha_asistencia y TIEMPO son de la tabla asistencia, estan unidos por el ID del empleado.

Ahora necesito acomodar los campos de la siguiente manera en una MATRIZ del report viewer.

ID_EMP | NOMBRE

```
             FECHA_ASISTENCIA | TIEMPO
```

---

¿Como debo agrupar los campos para que me de ese diseño y quede de la siguiente manera?

0001 JUAN

```
     17/05/2019   8.6 

     18/05/2019   8.6

     19/05/2019   8.6
```

0002 CARLOS

```
     18/05/2019   8.6

     19/05/2019   8.6
```

---

Ya intente diversas manera pero el campo FECHA_ASISTENCIA no me lo acomoda hacia abajo.

Espero su ayuda. de antemano gracias.

Comment: quizas puedas agruparlos desde el query y ya despues pasarlos a tu datset, ya una vez realizado esto solo agregas una tabla al reporte y le agregas tu dataset como tal.

Comment: muestra tu query para agruparlos desde ahi